# How to make a whole div flippable?

Tags: jquery

I am using quickFlip and it's super dope but I can't figure out how get an entire div to flip. The class used to flip the div doesn't work when attached to the actual div so I tried a p element inside the div with height and width set 100% and adding the flip class to that but now I can't nest headings inside there.

Any ideas on how ti make divs flippable using jQuery?

My current html for tiles is like this:

```
<div id="tile-wrap">
           <div class="size4 red fL i-projects"> 
        <h1>Project Portfolio</h1>
    </div>
            <div class="size4 orange fR i-interests">
        <h1>Career Interests</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="size4 purple fL i-resume">
        <h1>Resume</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="size4 green fR">
    </div>
    <div class="size4 x-l blue fL i-person">
        <h1>About Me</h1>
    </div>
     <div class="size4 yellow fR i-school">
        <h1>Education</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="size2 black fL i-email">
        <h1 style="text-align:left">Contact</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What I tried to with quickFlip was this but I can't get any headings or other content in there.

```
 <div id="tile-wrap">
    <div class="quickFlip">
         <div class="size4 red i-interests"> 
        <p class="quickFlipCta" style="height:100%;width:100%">
                <!-- this is not shown -->
                <h1>Project Portfolio</h1>
             </p>
         </div>
         <div class="size4 red">
          <p class="quickFlipCta" style="height:100%;width:100%"> 
              <h1>Provide Info Here</h1>
              <!-- this is not shown and niether is the heading above -->
              This might contain a list or something.
          </div>
    </div>
     </div>
```

This is makes the entire tile flippable but now I can't have any headings and I assume there are lots of things you can't nest in a p element so I can't so use those either.

Any solution? I wonder why the **class="quickFlipCta"** doesn't work on divs. If it did, it would be even more amazing.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do the flipping via CSS3 animations and 3d-transforms. That's much smoother and doesn't need as many resources as jQuery.

Have a look at these pages:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_3dtransforms.asp